# How to use comma noun and doing in sequence?

Tags: grammar, commas

I'm reading a book named "*Programming Rust*".

I couldn't get the meaning of the following sentence in the last chapter.

> Note that unsafe code must not depend on ordinary, safe traits being implemented correctly.

Is **ordinary** is a noun? And what is omitted after comma to connect the two sentences?

I thought it is saying

> Unsafe code requires not ordinary implementation. That's why safe traits are implemented correctly.

Is it right? It sounds odd to me, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The comma just means “and”.

In the example:

> Note that unsafe code must not depend on ordinary, safe traits being implemented correctly.

You can rephrase this as:

> Note that unsafe code must not depend on traits, **that are ordinary and safe**, being implemented correctly.

Or if you prefer:

> Note that unsafe code must not depend on {the correct implementation} of traits, {that are considered “ordinary” and “safe”}.

Comment: It's me or the sentence makes no sense? "UNSAFE code MUST NOT depend on SAFE traits"? I think that it made more sense if you replace "must" by "may". You may have unsafe code if you just implement ordinary safe traits.

Comment: I don’t take any position on whether the sentence is **true**.

Comment: I had the same suspicion about the meaning of the sentence. But I finally get it as I think the meaning is that "Safe traits are not relevant to unsafe code's safety. Unsafe code must depend on itself".

Comment: It's not true that the comma just means *and*. Assuming that it's substituting for anything at all (it doesn't have to be; *safe* could be acting as an appositive to *ordinary*), it's at least as likely that it's substituting for *or*.